# HTML/JS/Coldfusion - Multi Select on location.href possible?

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have some code that uses checkboxes:

```
input type="checkbox" onclick="location.href='test-launch.cfm?Code=7&After=8&OrderOn=9
```

when this checkbox is selected it reloads my page but here is where my issue is. When I select a different checkbox that passes a different value (below order on is a different value from above):

```
input type="checkbox" onclick="location.href='test-launch.cfm?Code=7&After=8&OrderOn=5
```

the page reloads and does not show any data with `orderOn = 9` anymore, it just shows data with `OrderOn = 5`. I was hoping "multiselect" would work with `location.href`. Is there a better way to handle this because `location.href` is "multiselecting".

Comment: Perhaps you should have a bunch or normal checkboxes with a submit button?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I tried that and it works, but wanted to see if there was a way I can somehow reload the page on click and having the ability to select multiple

Comment: So every time you click, another option gets added?

Comment: Yes that is how I want it to work

Comment: Use Javascript that gets the current page's `OrderOn` parameter, and adds the new value to it.

Comment: try form method=get onclick=submit()

Comment: Why are you reloading the page before the user finishes checking all the boxes in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code does what you want.

Your URLs will grow as you check more boxes. You don't need to use `[]` in the field name, ColdFusion automatically converts query string values of the same parameter name into a comma-delimited list of values. I think the latest version has some flag that converts the list to an array automatically.

This code just submits to the same page. Just change the value of the form's action to post it somewhere else.

`http://127.0.0.1/test/reload.cfm?whatever=2&whatever=4&whatever=6&whatever=8&whatever=10`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickMe').on('click', function() {
        $('#foo').submit();
    });
});

</script>

<cfparam name="url.whatever" type="string" default="" />

<form name="foo" id="foo" action="" method="get">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="10" index="x">
            <cfset checked = false />
            <cfif listFindNoCase(url.whatever, x)>
                <cfset checked = true />
            </cfif>
            <label for="whatever_#x#"><input type="checkbox" name="whatever" id="whatever_#x#" class="clickMe" value="#x#" <cfif checked>checked="checked"</cfif>>#x#</label><br />
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</form>

<cfdump var="#url#" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a multiselect, it passes each selected value as a different parameter in the URL, and they're normally given array-style names so that the server script will receive all of them. So the URL should look like this:

```
test-launch.cfm?Code=7&After=8&OrderOn[]=9&OrderOn[]=5
```

You can define a function that adds another order ID to the parameters.

```
function addOrder(n) {
    var search = location.search;
    if (search.length = 0) {
        search = "?OrderOn[]=" + n;
    } else {
        search += "&OrderOn[]=" + n;
    }
    location.href = 'test-launch.cfm' + search;
}
```

Then change your HTML to:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="addOrder(9)">
```